# Keycloak - Customize "sub" format in JWT token

Tags: jwt, single-sign-on, keycloak

I'm trying to find a way to change the "sub" format in JWT Token provided by Keycloak, I know it came from Keycloak User Id but i'm not sure we can't change it.

For example for now I have something like this :

"sub": "f:39989175-b393-4fad-8f84-628b9712f93b:testldap",

I would like it smaller .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that modifying 'sub' is a good idea, but if you sure, you can use something like that:

```
/**
 * Class for signing JWT (when you get tokens in base64 actually they are
 * signed by issuer server see https://jwt.io)
 */
public static class JwtSigner {

    private final KeyPair keyPair;
    private final String kid;

    public JwtSigner(String privateKeyPem) {
        PrivateKey privateKey = PemUtils.decodePrivateKey(privateKeyPem);
        PublicKey publicKey = KeyUtils.extractPublicKey(privateKey);
        keyPair = new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);
        kid = KeyUtils.createKeyId(keyPair.getPublic());
    }

    public String encodeToken(AccessToken accessToken) {
        return new JWSBuilder()
                .type("JWT")
                .kid(kid)
                .jsonContent(accessToken)
                .sign(Algorithm.RS256, keyPair.getPrivate());
    }
}


/**
 * This class allows you to update several token fields and re-encode token
 */
public static class JwtTransformer<T extends AccessToken> {

    private T token;

    public JwtTransformer(String tokenString, Class<T> tokenType) throws JWSInputException {
        try {
            token = JsonSerialization.readValue(new JWSInput(tokenString).getContent(), tokenType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new JWSInputException(e);
        }
    }

    public static <T extends AccessToken> T decode(String tokenString, Class<T> tokenType) throws JWSInputException {
        return new JwtTransformer<>(tokenString, tokenType).decode();
    }

    public static JwtTransformer<AccessToken> forAccessToken(String tokenString) throws JWSInputException {
        return new JwtTransformer<>(tokenString, AccessToken.class);
    }

    public static JwtTransformer<RefreshToken> forRefreshToken(String tokenString) throws JWSInputException {
        return new JwtTransformer<>(tokenString, RefreshToken.class);
    }

    public T decode() {
        return token;
    }

    public JwtTransformer transform(Consumer<T> consumer) {
        consumer.accept(token);
        return this;
    }

    public String encode(JwtSigner jwtSigner) {
        return jwtSigner.encodeToken(token);
    }

}
```

I used this classes for tests, but you can adopt them for your needs. Take a note that private key that required for JwtSigner initializaton is stored in keycloak DB, and can not be easily extracted via Admin Console UI. Check out result of

```
select VALUE
from KEYCLOAK.COMPONENT
         inner join KEYCLOAK.COMPONENT_CONFIG
                    on KEYCLOAK.COMPONENT.ID = KEYCLOAK.COMPONENT_CONFIG.COMPONENT_ID
where PARENT_ID = '%YOUR_REALM_NAME%'
  and PROVIDER_ID = 'rsa-generated'
  and COMPONENT_CONFIG.NAME = 'privateKey';
```

So finally you can do something like

```
String new AccessToken = JwtTransformer.forAccessToken(accessTokenString)
        .transform(token -> {
            token.subject(subModificationFunction(token.getSubject()))
        })
        .encode();
```